# Button in header use to push new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with header. I added in this header button,
and then I have created a class for this header of type `UICollectionReusableView`. Then I tried to add an action to this button in the class of type `UICollectionReusableView`

But, when I write this lines I got error

```
@IBAction func goToMovie(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let st = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "aaa") as! aaa
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(st, animated: true)

    }
```

the error msg: `value of type 'className' has no member 'storyboard'`

How I can go to other view by this button?

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting is because a `UICollectionReusableView` doesn't have a `storyboard` property. It also doesn't have a `navigationController` property.

You'll need to perform that transition not in the reusable view but from the viewController that contains it. In order to do that you'll need either a custom delegate or a callback block in order to tell the view controller the header was tapped and trigger the push.

**To use a block/closure/callback:**

In the reusable view add your completion closure:

`var completion: (() -> Void)?`

Next, in your `goToMovie` func remove those two lines and add then call the closure like this:

`completion?()`

Then in the view controller where you declare your header trigger the transition like this:

```
 . . .
headerView.completion = {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "WhateverYourSBNameIs",  bundle: nil)
    let aaaVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WhateverYourIdentifierIs") as! AAAViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(st, animated: true)
}
```

**To use a custom delegate**

Create the protocol:

```
protocol HeaderDelegate {
    func headerTapped(sender: UICollectionReusableView)
}
```

Then in the header add the delegate property

```
var delegate: HeaderDelegate?
```

Then when you declare the header:

```
 . . .
header.delegate = self
 . . .
```

Then make the view controller conform to the delegate:

```
extension ViewController: HeaderDelegate {

    func headerTapped(sender: UITableViewCell) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "WhateverYourSBNameIs",  bundle: nil)
        let aaaVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WhateverYourIdentifierIs") as! AAAViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(st, animated: true)

    }
}
```

If the view controller doesn't need to know which header was tapped you can remove the `sender: UITableViewCell` parameter from the delegate func.

Hope this helps. I would personally use the closure FWIW.

Comment: where I should write this `var completion: (() -> Void)?` just inside the class?

Comment: and these lines `headerView.completion = {
    let storyboard  . . . etc` where I put it?

Comment: the `var completion: (() -> Void)?` should go anywhere in the header file. 

the second one goes in the view controller when you declare the header inside `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView`

Comment: Sorry when I said the header file I realized that might be confusing. You were correct, it just needs to go anywhere inside the class for the `UICollectionReusableView`

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem please mark as correct. If not, I'd happy to help you with the implementation.